# float comparison for feet and inches is incorrect

Tags: java

feet and inches are expressed as float and I would expect 5.7 to be greater in this scenario. how to handle, since this returns 1

```
Float f1 = Float.parseFloat("5.7");
Float f2 = Float.parseFloat("5.10");
System.out.println(f1.compareTo(f2));
```

Comment: "_how to handle, since this returns 1_" - this returning 1 is the correct behavior, which means that f1 > f2. The Javadoc states: "_Returns: the value 0 if anotherFloat is numerically equal to this Float; a value less than 0 if this Float is numerically less than anotherFloat; and a value greater than 0 if this Float is numerically greater than anotherFloat._"

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Are you comparig 5.7 feet to 5.10 inches without converting them to the same units?

Comment: "I would expect 5.7 to be greater"—Then it does what you expect, so what is your question?

Comment: "I would expect 5.7 to be greater in this scenario". And indeed it is, because 5.7 is greater than 5.1. Fundamentally, representing "feet and inches" as a floating point number like this is a bad idea, because "5.1" and "5.10" represent the same floating point number.

Comment: @JonSkeet how to represent then

Comment: @khelwood I want a way to find that 5.10 is greater than 5.7, how to do? maybe my question wasn't clear

Comment: @Rpj what you can do is to seperate the left and right side from decimal point, convert then compare it. In my eyes is this way a good source for mistakes.

Comment: Separate "5.10" into two numbers (parsed as integers). Multiply the first number by 12 and add them together.

Comment: @khelwood what will be the effect by multiplying the numbers with 12?

Comment: Conventional notation would be 5' 7"

Answer (score 2):

I think I can see what the flaw in your approach is.

Reading between the lines, I think that that you want `"5.7"` to mean 5 feet 7 inches.  In fact, what you parse it as a `float`, it means 5 + 7/10ths of a foot.  Likewise `"5.10"` means 5 + 1/10th of a foot.  Which is **less than** `5.7`.

Note that this is the *normal* meaning of decimal numbers ... as we are all taught in primary school.  (And `5.7` is NOT less than `5.10`!)

---

Now ... if you want `5.7` to actually mean 5 foot 7 inches ... you will need to split the string `"5.7"` into two parts, convert the two parts into integers and do some arithmetic.

Something like this:

```
 String feetAndInches = "5.10";
 String[] parts = feetAndInches.split("\\.");
 float feet = parseFloat(parts[0]);
 if (parts.length == 1) {
     feet += parseFloat(parts[1]) / 12;
 }
```

---

But ... my advice is **don't do that**:

1. This notation is non-standard.
2. It is broken in the case that the number after the decimal is greater than 11.
3. The meaning is potentially ambiguous if there is no decimal point.
4. This notation doesn't provide a sane way of expressing lengths with fractions of an inch.

---

Finally:

> Feet and inches are expressed as float ...

They shouldn't be expressed in floating point notation.  Period.  See reasons above ...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using floats, you should create custom class to handle feet and inches, you can store them as integers. That class should also implements Comparable interface.

```
public class FeetAndInches implements Comparable<FeetAndInches> {
    private int feet;
    private int inches;

    public FeetAndInches(String s) {
        String[] parts = s.split("\\.");
        if (parts.length == 1) {
            feet = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            inches = 0;
        } else if (parts.length == 2) {
            feet = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            inches = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        } else throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(FeetAndInches that) {
        if (this.feet == that.feet) {
            return Integer.compare(this.inches, that.inches);
        } else {
            return Integer.compare(this.feet, that.feet);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**:
According to the @user16632363 comment you can store value only in inches :

```
public class FeetAndInches implements Comparable<FeetAndInches> {
    private int inches;

    public FeetAndInches(String s) {
        String[] parts = s.split("\\.");
        if (parts.length == 1) {
            inches = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) * 12;
        } else if (parts.length == 2) {
            inches = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) * 12 + Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        } else throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(FeetAndInches that) {
        return Integer.compare(this.inches, that.inches);
    }
}
```

You can use this class like that:

```
FeetAndInches f1 = new FeetAndInches("5");
FeetAndInches f2 = new FeetAndInches("5.10");
System.out.println(f1.compareTo(f2));
```

**Demo:** https://ideone.com/aaiOT8

Comment: I'd **store** the length in inches.  Convert from feet-and-inches on input and to feet-and-inches on output.  This will allow you to easily treat "1 foot 7 inches" and "19 inches" as the same length.

Comment: @user16632363 good point